Is carry-flag defined differently in Intel-x86 architecture than in ARM?
I'm scratching my head over this. Say, Intel x86 has the notion of a carry-flag (CF) which is bit-0 of EFLAGS. Then ARM has its own carry-flag (C) which is bit-29 of CPSR register.
I always assumed that they worked the same, but:
If I do (x64):
    mov     rax, 2
    sub     rax, 4    ; sets CF=1
    jc      lllp      ; jump if CF is set
    nop               ; never gets executed

lllp:

but if I do (ARM64):
    mov   x0, #2
    subs  x0, x0, #4   ; clears C=0
    bcs   lllp         ; branch if C is set
    nop                ; control always gets here

lllp

Are those carry-flags defined differently for these two architectures?

On x86, carry is borrow.  On ARM, carry is inverted borrow.  Yes, it's different.  I'll try to find a duplicate real quick.

@fuz wow, that's one way to confuse things. Thanks!

one is carry one is borrow.   some architectures invert carry out to make it a borrow.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag#Vs._borrow_flag
